# how to plot square shape highchart?

Tags: highcharts

am trying to plot a line graph in highchart but its rectangle in shape, how to make it in square shape.

[code here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/area-fillopacity/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'area'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        fillOpacity: 0.1
    }
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
});
```

[image]

Should be something like above img

Comment: Would you like to achieve something like is done here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3j485Lof/ ?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel. i plotted the same but the chart shape is rectangle. you may see the spacing between y axis ticks and x axis ticks. should be same

Comment: setting the `chart.height` as `100%` makes the chart height same as width - 1 : 1 ratio. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wg35z8eu/